# How can I place my data fields in COLUMNS in my Excel Pivot Table (Aspose Cells)

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, aspose-cells

I have already tried **"PivotFieldType.Column"** approach. It's **not** working because the source data Excel sheet looks like below

Excel sheet: Input Data

### Company Name FundsinUse LastDayCash

- My Company AA        -33848      37
- My Company AA        -33848      37
- My Company AA        -33848      37
- My Company BB        2188.75     55.5
- My Company BB        2188.75     55.5
- My Company BB        2188.75     55.5
- My Company BB        2188.75     55.5

=======================

I am creating Pivot table from this "Input Data" sheet and the generated Excel looks like below:

```
Row Labels          
My Company AA    FundsinUse    -101544
                 LastDayCash    111
My Company BB    FundsinUse     8755
                 LastDayCash    222
```

I would like to get output like below:

```
Row Labels          FundsinUse        LastDayCash
My Company AA        -101544            111
My Company BB         8755              222
```

Please help me to implement "Drag To Colum" on Data Fields using C#

Sample code

```
string sourceData = string.Format("='Input Data'!A1:BU{0}", totalRows + 1);

int indexOfFirstSheet = workbookDesigner.Workbook.Worksheets["FirstSheet"].Index;

Worksheet newWS = workbookDesigner.Workbook.Worksheets.Insert(indexOfFirstSheet + 1, SheetType.Worksheet, "My Pivot Sheet");

PivotTableCollection pivotTablesColl = newWS.PivotTables;

int index = pivotTablesColl.Add(sourceData, "A3", "My Pivot");

PivotTable pt = pivotTablesColl[index];
pt.RowGrand = true;
pt.ColumnGrand = true;

//Row field
pt.AddFieldToArea(PivotFieldType.Row, "Company Name");

// Data fields
pt.AddFieldToArea(PivotFieldType.Data, "FundsinUse");
pt.AddFieldToArea(PivotFieldType.Data, "LastDayCash");

PivotField fundsinUse = pt.DataFields[0];
fundsinUse.DragToColumn = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the **PivotTable.DataField** for your needs. Please see the following sample code and screenshots showing the input and output Excel files.

**C#**

```
Workbook wb = new Workbook("source.xlsx");

Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[0];

PivotTable pt = ws.PivotTables[0];

PivotField pdf = pt.DataField;

pt.AddFieldToArea(PivotFieldType.Column, pt.DataField);

pt.RefreshData();
pt.CalculateData();

wb.Save("output.xlsx");
```

**Screenshot - Before**

[image]

**Screenshot - After**

[image]

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: I have already tried "PivotFieldType.Column" approach. It's not working because the source data in question again. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
PivotTable pt = (PivotTable)hoja2.PivotTables("TD1");
pt.Format(XlPivotFormatType.xlReport1);
```

it´s works for me

Comment: You may want to put this solution in the place that it needs to be in the question.  Is this statement placed at the end of the code?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, when you have two or more Data fields and no Column fields, you have to add a "virtual" field into the Columns to make it display as expected.

```
// Add virtual field to column
pt.AddFieldToArea(PivotFieldType.Column, pt.DataField);
```

See this for a fuller example:
https://forum.aspose.com/t/how-do-you-add-a-count-column-to-a-pivottable/166240/8